# Zero beans when importing spring context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, applicationcontext

I try to load spring context from jar file in WEB-INF/lib/ like this(in spring-config-client.xml):

```
<import resource="classpath*:spring-configuration.xml" />
```

But when i try to use it:

```
ApplicationContext factory = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring-config-client.xml");
int k = factory.getBeanDefinitionCount();
```

k is equals to 0. How can I use beans from spring-config-client.xml?

When I write bean in spring-config-client.xml everything is fine, but I need beans from spring-config-client.xml.

Comment: The statement "When I write bean in spring-config-client.xml everything is fine, but I need beans from spring-config-client.xml." does not make any sense.

Comment: Sorry for my English. This statement means that if i write <import resource="classpath*:spring-configuration.xml" /> then I have 0 beans, but if i write <import resource="classpath*:spring-configuration.xml" /> <bean id="myBean" class="MyClass"/> than I have 1 bean.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make that work with the following workaround:

In your dependency project, create a configuration bean that looks like this:

```
   @Configuration
   @ImportResource("classpath:spring-configration.xml")
   public class MyContextConfiguration {

   }
```

Now you can instantiate this config bean in your dependent project's Spring context like any other bean:

```
<bean id="appWatcherConfig" class="MyContextConfiguration"/>
```

Worked fine for me.

Comment: Everytime I try to create bean with class from external jar I have "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException". But it is only with my own classes. I can make bean <bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"/> for example. I cant undestand why

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the directory your JAR file is residing in is not on your classpath. Make sure that your classpath is configured properly. Check out the build path settings on behalf of the IDE you're using and add the JAR manually if it's missing. Placing a JAR file in a directoy like WEB-INF doesn't gurantee that its classes are found by the bootstrap, extension or application classloader.

Comment: I use maven for dependencies. I can write `INewsDAO newsDAO = new NewsDAOImpl();` and there are no such exception. So I guess that classpath is ok.

Answer (score 0):

This depend on that your configuration in bean context like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd   
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd   
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd    
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd" lazy-init="false">
```

Try set: lazy-init="false" or default-lazy-init="false" in your spring context file and you must be sure that context file you did try to load having bean definition already.

Hope this help you!

Comment: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'lazy-init' is not allowed to appear in element 'beans'.

Comment: changed to default-lazy-init="false", but nothing happend

Comment: I need more details inside the "spring-configuration.xml" file, so i could help you more.